# Trying to make API call and fetch data

Tags: ios, swift, api, swiftui

This may be a noob question, but I am trying to make an API call with the trakt.tv API. However, no data is showing up, and I am unsure why this is occurring. This is my view code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var trendingMovies = [TrendingMovie]()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(trendingMovies, id: \.movie.ids.tmdb ) { trendingMovie in
                VStack {
                    Text(trendingMovie.movie.title)
                    Text("\(trendingMovie.movie.year)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Hello")
            .task {
                await fetchTrendingMovies()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchTrendingMovies() async {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.trakt.tv/movies/trending") else {
            print("Could not get trending movies.")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TrendingMovie].self, from: data) {
                print("We got the trending movies.")
                trendingMovies = decodedResponse
            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not get trending movies.")
        }
    }
}
```

This is my model code:

```
struct TrendingMovie: Codable {
    let watchers: Int
    let movie: Movie
}

struct Movie: Codable {
    let title: String
    let year: Int
    let ids: IDS
}

struct IDS: Codable {
    let trakt: Int
    let slug: String
    let imdb: String
    let tmdb: Int
}
```

I am still new to this stuff, so any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the first time I am working with an API on my own.

Comment: Remove the try? When parsing. What does the print(…) says?

Comment: By using `try?` instead of do/try/catch, your throwing away any chance of seeing an error

Comment: @CloudBalancing Removing the `try?` causes Xcode to give me an error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[TrendingMovie]'`.

Comment: @jnpdx What would be a better way of going about this?

Comment: Note, the url you use in your code, `https://api.trakt.tv/movies/trending` does not work, i.e it returns nothing when used in a browser. This could be the source of your problem.

Comment: To connect to the server, you have to build a request with the appropriate url, parameters and required headers, including 
your "trakt-api-key" etc... See the requirements here: https://trakt.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/api-url

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine If it's not too much to ask, could you provide an example on how I can do this? I've never seen anyone connect to an API like this before.

Comment: there are many examples on SO, and elsewhere using swift with async or combine and/or closures. Do some basic search, try a few things, you will learn a lot more than me providing you with an answer.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Sounds good. You know any examples on SO where I can start looking? I honestly don't know where to start, as all tutorials I have seen on getting an API have nothing to do with what seems to be required here.

Comment: have a look at these to get info on URLRequest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512063/async-request-to-unsplash-api-not-working-correctly

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552627/problem-making-api-request-with-async-await-in-swift-5-5

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70692615/displaying-state-of-an-async-api-call-in-swiftui

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71241937/urlrequest-error-the-given-data-was-not-valid-json

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58083255/how-to-display-json-data-from-api-in-swiftui/58084185#58084185

Comment: There are also a number of swift libraries on github that deal with trakt API. Maybe worth a look. 
eg: https://github.com/topics/trakt-tv?l=swift